# Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not be established in flutter

Tags: flutter

https://gist.github.com/bugudiramu/2c73f41a29ec8cd07dc7a592aaea3c65

When trying to parse this Dart file to find its dependencies:
  F:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\http-0.12.0+1\lib\http.dart
...the analyzer failed with the following error:
  Error in F:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\http-0.12.0+1\lib\http.dart: Expected to find ';'.

Comment: I used it
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Answer (score 0):

check your import statement as it lacks a semicolon `;` at the end of it:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the file in the cached package is corrupted.

To fix run

```
flutter packages pub cache repair
```

Comment: It just worked.Thank you so much it took me 2 days for figuring out the solution.Thank you.

Comment: Are you using VSCode? AndroidStudio and IntelliJ should prevent accidental editing of such files. As far as I know there was a change not too long ago to prevent this in VSCode as well and I'd expected this to have landed already.

Comment: Ensure you have the latest version of the DartCode plugin. If you see it again please report it as bug in https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues (with a link to this question)